# Why is this signal considered odd when v(t) is not equal to -v(-t)?

Tags: signal, math, fourier

In the solution of a problem, that asked to find the Fourier Series of the waveform, shown below. The coefficient of cosine part `an` is taken taken 0, because it is supposed to be an odd function.

[image]

But here, `v(t) = (V0*wt)/pi - V0`

And, `v(-t) = -(V0*wt)pi -V0`

Since, v(t) is not equal to -v(-t), it should not be an odd function. But the diagram of the wave suggests that it should be odd.

What is it that I'm missing here?

Comment: Your calculation is wrong because the function is not continuous. `v(t) = (V0*wt)/pi - V0` is only true in the `[0..2pi]` interval. Extend it graphically and you will see.

Comment: Odd harmonics are - π/2 and even are + π /2

Comment: @The Photon Sorry for the mistake. It has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function \$f(t)\$ is odd if \$-f(t) = f(-t)\$ for all \$t\$ in the range of \$f\$. The sawtooth function can be written as a piecewise linear function. The drawing you have provided of the sawtooth-wave is discontinuous, but can be made continuous if the vertical lines are replaced with **hollow** dots and the individual linear functions are open-ended, i.e. \$v_1(t) = ..., \: t\in]0,2\pi[ \:\:\: v_2(t) = ..., \: t\in]2\pi , 4\pi[\$...

As Eugene mentions in the comments, the problem in your calculation is likely due to the discontinuity of the function. I don’t think you can show the function is odd if you define it piecewise using linear functions. I think you have to define it as one continuous function. I could be wrong!

If you define your sawtooth function the following way things will work out:
$$v(t) = 2V_0 \Bigg(\frac{t-\pi}{p}- \bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t-\pi}{p} \bigg \rfloor \Bigg) $$

Using this function it seems that \$v(-t) = -v(t)\$ from the plots below, which indicates that the function is odd. I haven't been able to show it algebraically though: -

[image]